# Loading Workspace in shiny-App on shiny-server

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

**What I want to do**

I am trying to host a shiny app on shiny-server (Ubuntu). I have set up everything as shown in the official docs (using `nginx`).

Upon starting, the app needs to load a workspace (which can be updated in the background).
In RStudio the app works fine and loads the workspace as intended.

**The Problem**

Running on shiny-server, the app shows up at its target url and the base-functionality is working as intended, but the data is missing. The errors in the log-files show that the workspace variables can't be accessed, i.e. the workspace is either not loaded or there is no access to the environment.

I gave the user full access to read, write and execute files, so that the workspace can be loaded correctly, but that does not work.

**My question**

What is the correct way of loading a workspace into a shiny app on shiny-server to access its contents in the app?

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT**

**Example**

Try to first generate the data and then to start the app with a fresh empty environment. It can't find the data (not only on shiny-server, but in general).

Create some data and safe it. Then, clear the `.GlobalEnv` and start the app.

```
x <- iris
y <- mtcars
save.image(file=paste0(getwd(),"/workspace.RData"))
```

Here's the shiny-app:

```
library(shiny)

# Loading workspace prior to starting the app
setwd(getwd())
load("workspace.RData")

# UI
ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(sliderInput("in_slider",label="input",min=0,max=1,step=1,value=0)),
        mainPanel(plotOutput("out_plot"))
    )
)

# Server
server <- function(session,input,output) {
    output$out_plot <- renderPlot({plot(if(input$in_slider==0){x}else{y})})
}
shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

The goal is to correctly load the workspace into the app so that the `.GlobalEnv` is not empty when running the app.

PS: the calls to getwd() are meant as placeholders for the dirname of a custom path.

Comment: How are you loading the workspace in the code? Do you have an explicit call to `load()` somewhere? Where does the workspace file currently exist on the server?

Comment: I first set the working directory `setwd()` to the according folder of the workspace (which is in a subdirectory on the server). Then I call `load()` on the .RData file and lastly the code is continued by `shinyUI()`.

Comment: Is all your shiny code in one file? Are you sure the code that loads the data is running without error? It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. There's a lot of uncertainty about how your application is actually set up.

Comment: I added an example - it wasn't so easy to reproduce the error, but I realized that starting the app on an empty GlobalEnv is causing the problem. So how can I get the workspace loaded into the GlobalEnv? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Two general notes: (1) use `file.path` instead of `paste0` when working with paths. (2) you **never** need to prefix a path with `getwd()`. Just using `"workspace.RData"` as the path already does the correct thing (and, importantly, it does the *same* thing: your added code is therefore redundant).

Comment: Thanks for the notes. I know, I should've removed it here, but getwd() is just meant as a placeholder for the dirname of the path I use on my system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem by building a `global.R` file and sourcing it before starting the ui. The `global.R` file contains the call of `load("workspace.RData")`. In the docs I found that a `server.R` + `ui.R` structure will load the `global.R` file everytime, but using an `app.R` structure may require the call to `source()` at the beginning.
This worked for me (`app.R`):

```
source("global.R")
ui <- ...
```

The `global.R` file contains:

```
load("workspace.RData")
```